# Swapping divs from each function gets duplicated twice jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, swap

I want to swap 2 divs using jquery but when I tried to swap it using insertAfter() in gets inserted twice. Just want to specify that each parent element needs to only swap the divs once.

So in each parent element `wcmsd-step-container` I need to insert the `wcmsd-checkbox-item-description` class below the `wcmsd-step-title` class. But it gets duplicated twice when swapping it.

Can anyone point what's the right function to use on my jQuery code?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.wcmsd-step-container').each(function() {
    jQuery('.wcmsd-checkbox-item-description').insertAfter(jQuery('.wcmsd-step-title'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Step 1-->
<div class="wcmsd-step-container">

  <h2 class="wcmsd-step-title">What type of photo do you want?</h2>

  <div class="wcmsd-step-content">
    <label class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-title">choose your photo</label>
    <p class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-description">Select up to 122. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi accumsan faucibus proin nisi, risus vehicula. Fames metus, metus consectetur.</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!--Step 2-->
<div class="wcmsd-step-container">

  <h2 class="wcmsd-step-title">What type of video do you want?</h2>

  <div class="wcmsd-step-content">
    <label class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-title">choose your video</label>
    <p class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-description">Select up to 322. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi accumsan faucibus proin nisi, risus vehicula. Fames metus, metus consectetur.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code inside the loop has no relation to the loop, so it's just `for (i=0;i<2;++i)` with the inner code saying "take all descriptions and put them all after every title" - you get two because there's two, if you had 3,  you'd get 3 after each title.

You need to use `this` inside the loop to ensure the correct elements are moving to the correct place.

```
  $('.wcmsd-step-container').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.wcmsd-checkbox-item-description').insertAfter($(this).find('.wcmsd-step-title'));
  });
```

Updated snippet with a button to see before/after

```js
$("#btn").click(() => {
  $('.wcmsd-step-container').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.wcmsd-checkbox-item-description').insertAfter($(this).find('.wcmsd-step-title'));
  });
});
```

```css
.wcmsd-step-content { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">click me</button>

<!--Step 1-->
<div class="wcmsd-step-container">

  <h2 class="wcmsd-step-title">What type of photo do you want?</h2>

  <div class="wcmsd-step-content">
    <label class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-title">choose your photo</label>
    <p class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-description">Select up to 122. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi accumsan faucibus proin nisi, risus vehicula. Fames metus, metus consectetur.</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!--Step 2-->
<div class="wcmsd-step-container">

  <h2 class="wcmsd-step-title">What type of video do you want?</h2>

  <div class="wcmsd-step-content">
    <label class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-title">choose your video</label>
    <p class="wcmsd-checkbox-item-description">Select up to 322. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi accumsan faucibus proin nisi, risus vehicula. Fames metus, metus consectetur.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. forgot the $(this) part.